# Cannot set min-height to a fixed position div

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, overlay

What I wanna do is to create an overlay that I can reuse for different content with varying heights. However, if I use min-height or even height auto, the height still takes the entire window's height.

Is there a css way to do it or I'd need to use Javascript?

```css
.reusable-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #333;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="reusable-overlay">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras faucibus dapibus imperdiet. Aliquam aliquam pulvinar justo. Suspendisse ac laoreet tortor, eget dignissim lacus. Maecenas ac diam vitae orci eleifend lacinia in in ex. Vivamus consequat, mi
  id pulvinar aliquam, justo diam blandit ligula, vel blandit mauris sem eu risus. Quisque dignissim lorem et justo pellentesque gravida faucibus id mauris. Etiam faucibus est eget condimentum imperdiet. Donec tristique nibh id consequat interdum.
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/paVgry

Comment: Remove `bottom` ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyjMmw

Comment: @sol But I need it vertically and horizontally centered.

Comment: You could separate some of the styles between the container and the content. Use flexbox to center the content. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyMxzq

Comment: This is a bit better as it allows scroll if content overflows: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyjMYB

Comment: You want the content to not display more than a certain height? If that is the case you should be using `max-height` not `min-height`. Using `max-height` and `overflow: auto` I have displayed the overlay at less than window height https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMbwxB